# Testing flex with selenium without updating code

Tags: apache-flex, testing, selenium

I have been asked to check how to load test a flex application.

I've though about using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org), since it's precisely its job. I've also found that testing  Flex with Selenium requires extensions to Selenium. I've seen that there some of these :

- [sfapi](http://code.google.com/p/sfapi/)
- [flex-ui-selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/)

First, it seems that both requires me to rebuild my Flex application to test it. is it true ? Isn't there any way to automatically add handles ?
Second, when doing so, will I be able to do all kind of tests ? Load tests ? Performance tests ? All these in a continous way ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is one another way, but that is too complex to care or to implement. It's called OCR or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

Also you could use image recognition.

Alas, of course you can't automate a flash or a flex you need to rebuild it to use ExternalInterfaces to make some methods publicly available. That is how it is. The flash is one big chunk of an object there are no tiny parts that you could catch with anything else.

So you have these options only, nothing else i'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Genie can be used for testing flex apps without rebuilding the flex application, and its free. 
However, only Actionscript 3 is supported. AIR, AS1 & AS2 is not supported. Currently MX and Spark components cannot be tested, the doc says it can be done, but doesn't say how.

Another option is Sikuli, this is a image based testing tool. Its strength is its image heuristics, and does not use coordinates for comparison, unlike most image based testing tools.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to rebuild your application. There is an option to do this, but there are also options not too. The manuals clearly describe both approaches.
Check out also:
RiaTest
Flex Monkey
Neo4J